# Do Google-Chrome bookmarks allow other info to be stored besides name and URL?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I use this ability in FireFox and need to find it in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't think it's possible to do this in Chrome...

This is the bookmark editor.

[image: Edit bookmark window]

Comment: sadly this is all they offer for now